# How do I get ip address and mac address from arp output via Python regex?

Tags: python, arp

I would like to get mac addresses and corresponding ip addresses (e.g. as a dictionary with mac address as keys and ip addresses) as value from `arp` command line output on Ubuntu.

```
$ arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
XX.X.X.X(XX)                ether   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   C                     eth0
<host name>                 ether   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   C                     eth0
```

The regex for ip addresses `(?P<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})` and the regex for macs `(?P<mac>[0-9a-f]{2}[:]){5}([0-9a-f]{2})` each for it alone works fine. How can I combine those two and ignore everything between ip addresses and macs? How could I improve the ip address regex to match host names as well? In case there is a better alternative to using `arp` to get both, ip address and macs I am happy to use this command instead.

Comment: Splitting text into lines and lines into fields may give you better result than regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For joining them and ignore the intermediate information, just add the ".*" in the middle, so it matches anything, but is won't be assigned to a group:

```
(?P<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*([0-9a-f]{2}[:]){5}([0-9a-f]{2})
```

To account for hostnames, it will probably be better to caputure the first field without trying to make sure it is a proper IP or hostname. Just capture the first field, until the space:

```
^(?P<ip>[^\s]+)
```

So the first field with the hole and the MAC ends up being:

```
^(?P<ip>[^\s]+).*(?P<mac>(?:[0-9a-f]{2}:){5}[0-9a-f]{2})
```

Comment: When I debugged the regex on https://regex101.com/ your first suggestion did match the group ip (ip as well as hostnames) but did not match the macs correctly. Your second suggestion with mach group added `^(?P<ip>[^\s]+).*(?P<mac>[0-9a-f]{2}[:]){5}([0-9a-f]{2})` matched group ip correctly (ip as well as hostnames) but did not for macs as well.

Comment: Well, I relied in the fact that you told us that your mac regex was working properly for your needs. If that's not the case... don't blame me :P
You just need to put the parenthesis in the proper place: `^(?P<ip>[^\s]+).*(?P<mac>([0-9a-f]{2}:){5}[0-9a-f]{2})`

Comment: in case I used the mac regex only it did work??? Anyway, thx a lot. Please per review fix in answer...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to extract by columns from shell itself and there by reducing the overhead of text parsing.

```
a = subprocess.check_output(["arp | awk '{print $1,$3}'"], shell = True)

# Ip address
for i in a.split('\n')[:-1]:
    print(i.split()[0])

# Mac address
for i in a.split('\n')[:-1]:
    print(i.split()[1])
```

Comment: This command line expression is a bit clunky to call with `subprocess.check_output(...)` and the like...

Comment: I believe it does  save you from lot of overhead when you actually try to parse with regex

Comment: Alright. It is just a suggestion. I added the subprocess call too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Python **scapy** module to get the mac

```
from scapy.all import *
def get_mac(ip_address):
    responses,unanswered = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=ip_address),timeout=2,retry=10)
# return the MAC address from a response
    for s,r in responses:
        return r[Ether].src
    return None

print(get_mac("192.168.31.14"))
```